# How to get second td class if i know first

Tags: xpath

My first question here, sorry if i do something wrong.

I have code

```
<div class="detail_block_param">
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
            <tr>
                <td class="name">1st par</td>
                <td class="value">Swiss</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div><div class="detail_block_param">
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
            <tr>
                <td class="name">2nd par</td>
                <td class="value">mechanic</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

I need to get "value" class if name="1st par".
I try

```
//h:td[2][*[contains(.,'1st par')]]/../h:td[last()]/h:a/text()
```

but its not worked for me.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
'//td[@class="name"][contains(text(), "1st par")]/following-sibling::td[@class="value"]'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to do it using JQuery...Here is the solution:

```
$(".detail_block_param td:contains('1st par')").next().html()
```

Fiddler result for the same:

http://jsfiddle.net/CPQ8C/